# Got Error when add help shift sdk android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I using Android in Eclipse and need to add Help Shift SDK. I using jar from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.helpshift/android-sdk/3.9.0).

After I add and build, everything work fine.

But when I run my project in devcice. There are error will be appear.
My error I got

```
11-24 10:34:48.261: E/OpenGLRenderer(8517): Cannot generate texture from bitmap
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.helpshift.R$string
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at com.helpshift.HSActivity.isTablet(HSActivity.java:161)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at com.helpshift.HSActivity.setSize(HSActivity.java:167)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at com.helpshift.HSActivity.onCreate(HSActivity.java:144)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at com.helpshift.HSFaqs.onCreate(HSFaqs.java:45)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5021)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5108)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
11-24 10:35:02.815: E/AndroidRuntime(8517):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```